# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected in

Tags: php, html, mysql

Me sale el siguiente error:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected in C:\xampp\htdocs\StudioGamer\index.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\StudioGamer\index.php(8): PDO->prepare('SELECT id, nomb...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\StudioGamer\index.php on line 8

Ya revise todo mi código y no le encuentro solución, espero puedan ayudarme.

```php
<!--database.php-->
<?php
class Database{
    private $hostname="localhost";
    private $database ="gamer_studio";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "1234";
    private $charset = "utf8";

    function conectar()
    {
        try{
        $conexion = "mysql:host=" .$this->hostname . "; dbname" . $this->database . "; charset" . $this->charset;
        $options = [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
        ];

        $pdo = new PDO($conexion, $this->username, $this->password, $options);

        return $pdo;
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error conexion: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
      } 
    }
}
?>
```

```html
<!--index.php-->
<?php

require 'config/database.php';
$db = new Database();
$con = $db->conectar();

$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT id, nombre, precio FROM productos WHERE activo=1");
$sql->execute();
$resultado = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

La línea donde realizas la conexión es incorrecta, te falta hacer la igualación, en este caso utilizando `=` en *dbname* y *charset*:

```
$conexion = "mysql:host=" .$this->hostname . "; dbname=" . $this->database . "; charset=" . $this->charset;
```